# How to append an element to dictionary when the key exist or not exist in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I want to append an element to dictionary. And I want to make it if the key not exist. 
My solution is this:

```
if let _ = eventsBySection[key] {
   eventsBySection[key]?.append(event)
} else {
    eventsBySection[key] = [event]
}
```

Is it possible to write this code better? or in one line?

Comment: Just use an extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nil coalescing operator `??` and provide an empty array in case of nil:

```
eventsBySection[key] = (eventsBySection[key] ?? []) + [event]
```

**edit/update**:

Swift 4 or later You can use Dictionary Key-based subscript with default value

```
eventsBySection[key, default: []].append(event)
```