# Extension optional Array with Optional Element. Is it even possible?

Tags: swift, generics

I have a protocol `FooProtocol`. and a class `Bar<Foo:FooProtocol>`. Inside a class an Array `var mess: [Foo?]?` to keep `[foo1, foo2, nil, foo3...]` or `nil`
And I try to make extension for this array to count new Foo object. I prefer to have protocols, because Foos could be very different objects delivered from outer world.

```
protocol FooProtocol {
  ....
  init(from heaven: Int)
}

extension Optional where
  Wrapped: Collection,
  Wrapped.Element == Optional,
  Wrapped.Element.Wrapped: FooProtocol // 'Wrapped' is not a member type of 'Wrapped.Element'
{
  var united: Wrapped.Element.Wrapped { // Nope
    let i = ...
    return Wrapped.Element.Wrapped(from: i) // Nope
    
  }
}

class Bar<Foo:FooProtocol> {
  var mess: [Foo?]?
  init (with mess: [Foo?]?) {
    self.mess = mess
  }
  var important: Foo {
    return mess.united
  }
}
```

Any ideas? I'm blocked.

**Edit 1:**

After Leo suggestions I changed some parts of my code. But still stucked. This time more code from Playgrounds.

Any object that could be converted into '[Double]'. Could be color (as RGBA), Bezier curve, square, whatever...

```
public protocol FooProtocol {
    var atomized: () -> [Double] {get}
    static var count: Int {get}
    init(_ array:[Double])
    init()
}


public extension Array where Element: FooProtocol {
    var average: Element {
        var resultAtoms: [Double] = []
        let inputAtoms = self.map {$0.atomized()}
        for i in 0..<Element.count {
            let s = inputAtoms.reduce(into: 0.0, {$0 += $1[i]}) / Double (Element.count)
            resultAtoms.append(s)
        }
        return Element(resultAtoms)
    }
}

extension Optional where
    Wrapped: Collection,
    Wrapped.Element == Optional<FooProtocol>
{
    typealias Foo = Wrapped.Element.Wrapped // Doesn't work. How to get class?
    
    var average: Foo { // I cannot use Wrapped.Element, it's Optional
        if let thatsList = self {
            let withOptionals = Array(thatsList) // OK, its [Optional<FooProtocol>]
            let withoutOptionals = thatsList.compactMap({$0}) // OK, its [FooProtocol]
            // This is funny, called from class works and makes 'bingo'.
            return withoutOptionals.average // Error: Value of protocol type 'FooProtocol' cannot conform to 'FooProtocol'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
        } else {
            return Foo() // Hello? init Wrapped? Foo? How to get Foo()?
        }
    }
}

class Bar<Foo:FooProtocol> {
    var mess: [Foo?]?
    init (with mess: [Foo?]?) {
        self.mess = mess
    }
    func workOn() {
        let z:Foo = mess.average  // OK, I can make 'mess.average ?? Foo()' but prefer not do it
    }
    // Thats OK
    func workHard() { // To prove 'Array extension where Element: FooProtocol' works
        if let messExist = mess {
            let withoutOptionals =  messExist.compactMap({$0})
            let bingo = withoutOptionals.average //It's OK
        }
    }
}

class SomeFoo : FooProtocol {
    static var count = 3
    required init() {
        a = 0
        b = 0
        c = 0
    }
    
    required init(_ array: [Double]) {
        self.a = Int(array[0])
        self.b = Float(array[1])
        self.c = array[2]
    }
    
    var atomized: () -> [Double]  {
        return {return [Double(self.a), Double(self.b), self.c]}
    }
    
    var a: Int
    var b: Float
    var c: Double
}

let aFoo = SomeFoo([1, 2, 3])
let bFoo = SomeFoo([7, 9, 1])
let cFoo = SomeFoo([2, 6, 5])

let barData = [nil, aFoo, nil, bFoo, cFoo]
let barWithData = Bar(with: barData)
let barWithoutData = Bar<SomeFoo>(with: nil)
```

Maybe I should forget about extending array and make some functions inside a class (I'm almost sure I will need those functions somewhere else)

**Edit 2**

Even if I try to simplify and to make extension for Array I found troubles.

```
extension Array where
    Element == Optional<FooProtocol>
{
    func averageNils <Foo: FooProtocol>() -> Foo {
        
        let withOptionals = Array(self) // OK, its [Optional<FooProtocol>]
        let withoutOptionals = self.compactMap({$0}) // OK, its [FooProtocol]
        return withoutOptionals.average as! Foo // Error: Value of protocol type 'FooProtocol' cannot conform to 'FooProtocol'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide `FooProtocol` and `Bar` class code as well? So we can understand more what you're trying to do.

Comment: "to count new Foo object", note sure what you mean by _new_ here but is the goal simply to count the number of elements in the `mess` array?

Comment: It’s a bit more complicated. I have to count new Foo object based on existing and nonexisting Foo objects in exisisting and not existing [Foo] arrays.

Comment: First change your array declaration from optional to non optional and initialize it with an empty collection. Why would you need to declare your collection optional?

Comment: Btw why would you need to extend only optional collections? Just extend the collection itself it would be available to the optional collection as well

Comment: This is a good question. It has some connection with getting them from dictionary. It happen there is no key for them.

Comment: You can use  Dictionary Key-based subscript with a default value `[]` https://stackoverflow.com/a/46089006/2303865

Comment: @Leo, i will count missing elements from other elements of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, it *should* work as you did, but one never knows what happens in the swift compiler world (and especially it's error messages).

Anyway, you can circumvent digging deeper into  `Wrapped.Element.Wrapped` by specifyig the `Wrapped.Element` more precisely to be an `Optional<FooProtocol>`:

```
protocol FooProtocol {}
class Foo : FooProtocol {}

extension Optional where
  Wrapped: Collection, //OK
  Wrapped.Element == Optional<FooProtocol> // still good
{
   var unfied: Wrapped.Element  // Should be 'Foo' if self is '[Foo?]?' {
   {
    return 1 == 0 ? nil : Foo()
   }
}
```

Comment: With "Wrapped.Elemen : Optional<FooProtocol>" I have "Type 'Wrapped.Element' constrained to non-protocol, non-class type 'Optional<FooProtocol>'" error. with "==" I have "Protocol 'FooProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"

Comment: I don't get an error when constrainting `Wrapped.Element == Optional<FooProtocol> ` (Swift 5.1)

Comment: This is because the FooProtocol content is missing, but I assume that it contains an associatedtype or a Self reference. This is way it can only be used as a generic constraint. @Łukasz you should provide the full declaration of FooProtocol. This is a big constraint to work with.

Comment: From Swift forums by Jens Persson: ”The feature you're looking for is "parameterized extensions" and is not yet available in the language.” Maybe you have some more future version of Swift? :)

Comment: Oh! Yes, I had some associated type declared in protocol. When I removed compiler said "yes".

Comment: The comment above applies to this post as well

Comment: Thank you, Leo. I redesigned code a little bit and now seems so be OK.

Comment: ...but only in Playground. While I cannot remove Equatable conformance from my FooProtocol, I cannot make `Wrapped.Element == Optional<FooProtocol>`. Without Equatable works. With Equatable doesn't.